# Is it possible to implement IP based Ratelimiter using Resilience 4j in java?

Tags: java, implementation, rate-limiting, resilience4j

I was surfing internet on implementing IP address based ratelimiter using Resilience-4j in java programming language.  But, i didn't find any relevant articles or information on this.

Can somebody share your thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.